# How to send HtmlGenericControl content from controller to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to display `HtmlGenericControl` content on my view.

I created an `HtmlGenericControl` in a controller to add some thumbnail images to it and now want to display it on view.

Comment: Why are you using that control? It's for Web forms not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve but I wouldn't use an `HtmlGenericControl` in a MVC application. Normally you want your controllers to pass only data to the views and let them handle all the presentation.

Maybe you can have a look at [partial views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Anyway, if you really want the output of your `HtmlGenericControl` in your view you can try to pass the generated HTML. To obtain it you can do something like:

```
HtmlGenericControl ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
// set your content here
StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter htmlStringWriter= new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(htmlStringBuilder));
ctrl.RenderControl(htmlStringWriter);
String output = htmlStringBuilder.ToString();
```